# Kibana proxy pass not working

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, kibana-4

i'm taring to configure a revers Apache proxy for Kibana ES in AWS to be able to limit access via google oauth.
current setup: kibana.exemple.com 
this configuration works

```
 <Location />
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require valid-user
 ProxyPass http://kibana.aws.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
 ProxyPassReverse http://kibana.aws.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
 </Location>
```

but ineed to put kibana in /aws/ location in the same vhost

```
<Location /aws/>
 AuthType openid-connect
 Require valid-user
 ProxyPass http://kibana.aws.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
 ProxyPassReverse http://kibana.aws.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
 </Location>
```

and access http://kibana.exemple.com/aws/_plugin/kibana/

kibana will fail loading and get error :(

> Error: Not Found at respond
>   (http://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:85132:15)
>   at checkRespForFailure
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:85100:7) at
>   htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:83738:7 at
>   wrappedErrback
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:20902:78)
>   at wrappedErrback
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:20902:78)
>   at wrappedErrback
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:20902:78)
>   at htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:21035:76
>   at Scope.$eval
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:22022:28)
>   at Scope.$digest
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:21834:31)
>   at Scope.$apply
>   (htt://kibana.exemple.com/_plugin/kibana/index.js?_b=6103:22126:24)

removed p from http to be able to post.

will apprise any input on this on this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i manage to solve the problem:

```
<LocationMatch "(/_plugin/kibana/|/_nodes|/.kibana4|/nginx|logstash-)(.*)">
                ProxyPass http://kibana.aws.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/$1$2
                ProxyPassReverse http://kibana.aws.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/$1$2
         </LocationMatch>
```